# Let $M$ be the cov. matrix of a MV Gaussian. Then find $Q$ s.t. $QMQ^T=I$.

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $M$ be the covariance matrix of a multivariate Gaussian. Then find $Q$ s.t. $QMQ^T=I$.

---

Is there a way to find such a $Q$? And does it always exist? I've tried to use the fact that $M$ is diagonalizable (since it's symmetric positive semidefinite), but I didn't get to a solution.

Is there a general way to find such a matrix $Q$? In case this is a famous decomposition, then I'm just happy if you provide me the name of it.

Comment: Singular value decomposition and the spectral theorem comes to mind. Schur decomposition is mentioned on wikipedia page for the spectral theorem.

Comment: If $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, then what is $Q^{-1}$?  Is $Q^{-1}$ also an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Thanks @Emil and Brian Borchers for the hints! See below my current proof. If you have any Idea how to justify 4 let me know please.

Comment: If $M$ is not definite this is impossible, in the way you wrote it. Otherwise, look up Cholesky

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints. Here's my proof that such a $Q$ can always be found.

1. Since $M$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, there exists a eigendecomposition $$
   M=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}.
   $$ (@Emil)
2. Now, since $M$ is real and symmetric $Q$ is orthogonal. Thus $Q^{-1}=Q^T$. (@Brian Borchers )
3. Furthermore, since $M$ is positive semidefinite all eigenvalues are $\geq 0$ thus, we can write $\Lambda=\Lambda^{1/2}\Lambda^{1/2}$.
4. **Open Question: Here I somehow would need the fact that $M$ is not only positive semidefinite, but positive definite (in order for $\Lambda$) to be invertible. Is there some way to prove this? Would $M$ not be the covariance of a MV Gaussian if it wasn't positive definite? (In that case one eigenvalue would be zero, ...)**

Now, using these facts we get
$$
\begin{align*}
&&
M&=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}
&& (1)
\\
&&
&=Q\Lambda Q^T
&&(2)
\\
&&
&=Q\Lambda^{1/2}\Lambda^{1/2} Q^T
&&(3)
\\
&&
&=Q\Lambda^{1/2}I\Lambda^{1/2} Q^T
&&(4)\quad|\,\,(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}Q^T\cdot
\\
\\
\Longleftrightarrow&&
(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}Q^TM
&=\underbrace{(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}\underbrace{Q^TQ}_{=I}\Lambda^{1/2}}_{=I}I\Lambda^{1/2} Q^T
=I\Lambda^{1/2}Q^T
&&|\,\,\cdot Q(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}
\\
\\
\Longleftrightarrow&&
\underbrace{(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}Q^T}_{V:=}M\underbrace{Q(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}}_{V^T}
&=I\underbrace{\Lambda^{1/2} \underbrace{Q^TQ}_{=I}(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}}_{=I}
=I
\end{align*}
$$

So, $V:=(\Lambda^{1/2})^{-1}Q^T$ is the matrix s.t. $VMV^T=I$.

Comment: This can only be done if $M$ is invertible.  After all, $1 = \det(I) = \det(V) \det(M) \det(V^{T})$ only if $\det(M) \neq 0$.